# show payment method in site

Tags: php, css

i create Joomla site
i build some shop with hikashop module and costume it

in Cart if i go tab 3 ( for payment method ) i cant added more payment method

can anyone help me why i cant do that ?
for better understanding i send pic and tell you more info

[image]
i create 5 payment method in hikashop

[image]
i build buying method in step 3 u can choice you payment method

[image]
but in my site i can see just 3 from 5 method

how i can 2 more method in my site ?

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Questions about the CMS and its extensions (like Hikashop) are on-topic there.  After you join JSE, if you would like this page to migrated to the dedicated community, I can help with that -- just say so.

Comment: @mickmackusa im be there how i can merge this ? thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you only see 3 out of 5 payment methods then probably there is a restriction that prevents those methods from being displayed. Do you use another extension for integration with a payment provider that might need a bit of extra configuration?

If I see it correctly then the 3 methods displayed are the ones that don't need anything special to work so I would checkout if the configuration of the other 2 is OK.